# SSH Difference between ./ and sh

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

I wrote simple file "hello world" and try to execute it on virtual server by SSH.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
```

Of course I give `chmod +x`

Then on one server I try to execute it by command:

```
./file.sh
```

And I have reply:

```
-bash: ./file.sh: Permission denied
```

Works only when I start it by command:

```
sh file.sh
```

On other server both commands works fine...

So my question is: is there any kind of permission that prevents execution with **`./`** command?

What is the difference between the two commands?

Comment: What shell do you use? What is the output of `/bin/bash file.sh`?

Comment: /bin/bash file.sh - works fine.
I have this problem on zenbox.pl server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem may be mounted with `noexec`. I recreated this in my Debian. The behavior fits.

When you run `./file.sh` it is treated as executable; however with `/bin/bash file.sh` the executable is `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extract from the manual (`man sh`):-

> If command line arguments besides the options have been specified,
>   then the shell treats the first argument as the name of a file from
>   which to read commands (a shell script), and the remaining arguments
>   are set as the positional parameters of the shell ($1, $2, etc).
>   Otherwise, the shell reads commands from its standard input.

Thus in `sh file.sh` the specified file `file.sh` becomes an input source for the shell, so needs to be readable, but need not be executable. The same is true of the `source` or `.` command, so the following will all run a non-executable file:-

```
sh ./file.sh
sh<./file.sh
. ./file.sh
source ./file.sh
```

The last two will execute in the current shell, the first two in a sub-shell. Note that `sh -c ./file.sh` will require `file.sh` to executable, while `sh -c ". ./file.sh"` needn't. Note also that if `file.sh` is executable, then its location needs to be in `$PATH` if it is called directly, unless a specific path (`./` in the example) is included:

```
file.sh
```

However, the four previous examples do not need the `./` prefix, as the file to read will always be sought in the current directory (though the `.` and `source` commands will also search `$PATH`).

Two final points:-

1. The four examples work only for script files: they will all fail if `file.sh` is a binary executable.
2. In the four examples, the `#!/bin/bash` comment is just a comment: the executing `sh` will read it as such and will *not* clone `bash` to execute the rest of the file, so any `bash` extensions in it will cause errors.